# Is there an error in the datasheet for the AOZ1284?

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, buck, datasheet

I am working with AOZ1284A a buck converter.

Datasheet:http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ1284PI.pdf

According to the datasheet:
[image]

I think they mistaken 5000 for 55000. But this works only with the 2 first frequency. for the swF of 1M I get 50K.

My Question :

- Am I right?
- Is it normal to take 1M as an approximation of 1065K?

(with 46.6K and when we replace 5000 with 55000 we get Rf=1065K)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem there is a typo in the formula.

And yes, it says in the datasheet electrical characteristics that the switching rate with a 46.6k resistor will be 1 MHz typically, with range of 0.8 to 1.2 MHz, so given the 20% tolerance, the approximation of the frequency is close enough not to include any decimals.